# What is the ioreg command for?

Tags: macos

What is Mac OS X's `ioreg` command for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command `ioreg` located in /usr/sbin/ioreg is used to display the I/O Kit registry. [Man Page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/ioreg/).